# Use the results of SUM in the same query

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, postgresql-performance

```
SELECT 
business_period,
SUM(transaction.transaction_value) AS total_transaction_value,
SUM(transaction.loss_value) AS total_loss_value,
(total_transaction_value - total_loss_value) AS net_value
FROM transaction
GROUP BY business_period
```

The above does not work as `total_transaction_value` and `total_loss_value` are not from the `transaction` table. Is there a way to make this query work?

Note: this query involves 500 million rows, so need to efficient.

Question:
Some answers have suggested that `SUM(transaction.transaction_value) - SUM(transaction.loss_value)` is cached and won't need to be computed again where as others are suggesting that I should as a derived table / subsequery to avoid repeated computation. Could someone point to something that could settle the difference in opinion?

I am using postgres 9.3.

ANSWER:

I want to quote erwin's comment here:

`I ran a quick test with 40k rows and the winner was the plain version without subquery. CTE was slowest. So I think my first assumption was wrong and the query planner understands not to calculate the sums repeatedly (makes sense, too). I have seen different results with more complex expressions in the past. The planner does get smarter with every new version`

Comment: Just a little note: Don't use reserved words / keywords in your tabledefinitions. In most cases it will work, but you might get some weird behaviour. A list of keywords for postgresql: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html

Comment: Hey @DKSan, thanks for the tips. This is not actually my schema but a little thing I just wrote for this question. But next time I will make sure that make the example nicer too. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT 
business_period,
SUM(transaction.transaction_value) AS total_transaction_value,
SUM(transaction.loss_value) AS total_loss_value,
(SUM(transaction.transaction_value) - SUM(transaction.loss_value)) AS net_value
FROM transaction
GROUP BY business_period
```

Comment: I take that SUM(transaction.transaction_value) is cached and won't need to be computed again?

Comment: @alumns Yes, The sum is only computed once.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sum` again

```
SELECT 
business_period,
SUM(transaction.transaction_value) AS total_transaction_value,
SUM(transaction.loss_value) AS total_loss_value,
(SUM(transaction.transaction_value) - SUM(transaction.loss_value)) AS net_value
FROM transaction
GROUP BY business_period
```

Comment: I take that SUM(transaction.transaction_value) is cached and won't need to be computed again?

Comment: Yeah you have cached but the db doesn't identify the `total_transaction_value` as column name.. so you need to use the function again

Answer (score 0):

Just explicitly reiterate the SUMs (I *believe* they are only calculated once):

```
SELECT 
  business_period,
  SUM(transaction.transaction_value) AS total_transaction_value,
  SUM(transaction.loss_value) AS total_loss_value,
  SUM(transaction.transaction_value) - SUM(transaction.loss_value) AS net_value
FROM transaction
GROUP BY business_period
```

Alternatively you can use a derived table subquery, which should force it to calculate only once if the above does not do so implicitly - although there may be some additional overhead depending on what the optimizer sees:

```
SELECT business_period,
  total_transaction_value,
  total_loss_value,
  (total_transaction_value - total_loss_value) AS net_value
FROM
(
    SELECT 
       business_period,
       SUM(transaction.transaction_value) AS total_transaction_value,
       SUM(transaction.loss_value) AS total_loss_value,
    FROM transaction
    GROUP BY business_period
) x
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a **subquery** to avoid repeated computation:

```
SELECT *, total_transaction_value - total_loss_value AS net_value
FROM  (
   SELECT business_period
        , SUM(transaction_value) AS total_transaction_value
        , SUM(loss_value)        AS total_loss_value
   FROM   transaction
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) sub;
```

Or a [CTE (common table expresson)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) to actually *force* this, since CTEs pose as optimization barriers. A subquery is generally faster for simple cases like this. Postgres knows better, when collapsing subqueries is faster.

Comment: so SUM(transaction.transaction_value) - SUM(transaction.loss_value)  as the others have suggested will lead to repeated computations?

Comment: @alumns: Yes - Postgres is free to optimize, though. SQL is a declarative language. Only a CTE actually forces a single calculation - at the cost of more overhead. A subquery is probably cheaper. Don't just take my word, test with [`EXPLAIN ( ANALYZE, TIMING OFF)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-explain.html) to see which is faster. You won't find much of a difference ...

Comment: @alumns: I ran a quick test with 40k rows and the winner was the plain version without subquery. CTE was slowest. So I think my first assumption was wrong and the query planner understands not to calculate the sums repeatedly (makes sense, too). I have seen different results with more complex expressions in the past. The planner does get smarter with every new version ...

Comment: Thank you again with your always in depth answers! :)